# Show total comments per post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-4.3

I have problem with showing total comments in wordpress. The comment's total didn't show in right place.

Here's what it looks like
[image: Here's what it looks like]

What I want is
[image: What I want is]

Here's my code

```
'<li class="meta-item meta-total-comments"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i>' . comments_number() . '</li>'
```

Comment: @LoaiNagati sorry, it's not launch yet.

Comment: This could be happening for plenty of reasons then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
'<li class="meta-item meta-total-comments"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i><a href="'.comments_link().'" class="scroll comments_link">'. comments_number(__( 'No comments', 'mytheme'), esc_attr__('1 comment', 'mytheme'), esc_attr__('% comments', 'mytheme')).'</a></li>'
```

If this doesn't work you can try with:

```
'<li class="meta-item meta-total-comments"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i><a href="'.get_comments_link().'" class="scroll comments_link">'. get_comments_number( $post_id )).'</a></li>'
```

Look at the example [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_comments_number) to get the same functionality with `get_comments_number` as with `comments_number`.